# Rails - Error performing ActionMailer::DeliveryJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, smtp

I am using SMTP in Production with Rails.

I am sending the email with `deliver_later`, if that is relevant.

I am receiving the following error:

```
E, [2019-01-28T20:13:35.610611 #63161] ERROR -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [97578598-066d-46a0-b7fb-9daeb2eaf689] Error performing ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 97578598-066d-46a0-b7fb-9daeb2eaf689) from Async(mailers) in 1455.28ms: EOFError (end of file reached):
```

Here is my config:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => 'postal.<redacted>',
    :port => '25',
    :authentication => 'plain',
    :user_name => '<redacted>'/main',
    :password => '<redacted>''
  }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => '<redacted>'', :protocol => 'https' }
```

I am fairly new to rails so any help would be appreciated.

I am using `Ruby  2.3.7` and `Rails 5.2.2`.

**Other similar posts on stack overflow haven't seemed to fix this.**

Comment: Are you using rails credentials to store your user_name and password?

Comment: No, they are stored inside the `production.rb` file.

Comment: Did you install Sidekiq or another background job processor to perform job asynchronously (`deliver_later`) ? Also did you try to deliver your email using `deliver_now` ? Might be a good first test before making the delivery async

Comment: What u mean redacted

Comment: Private information that I would prefer not to reveal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out the problem was on the mail server as I was using. The confusion was that Rails did not seem to report this clearly. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe also important: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/2427